# Impersonation on IIS-hosted OData Service

Tags: c#, wcf, http, iis, odata

I created an **IIS**-hosted **WCF OData-service** two publish a table from a **MS-SQL database**. When I try to access the service from a custom **C#**-project I get an error stating that *'NT-AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS'* can not access the database.

The **IIS** is configured to impersonate the user and when I request the same URL from a browser I´ll get the data, so I suspect when my own **C#**-application is executing the request, for some reason the user is not impersonated properly.

Here are the facts:

- **ASP-Impersonation** on the **IIS** is enabled.
- Windows-Authentication with **NTLM**-only is the only activated authentication method.
- The application-pool is running integrated (v4.0) with `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration` switched off.
- As stated above, I am able to access all the data through a browser.
- I am able to access the OData-metadata from my client-application, so authentication is basically working.

Here is a snippet of my client-code:

```
var serviceContextContext = new DataServiceContext(_url);
_serviceContextContext.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;
_serviceContextContext.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;
_serviceContextContext.SendingRequest += DataServiceContextContextSendingRequest;

// Here is where I get an internal server error
var response = _serviceContextContext.Execute<ODataEntity>(entitySetRequestUri);

private void DataServiceContextContextSendingRequest(object sender, SendingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)e.Request;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _password,_domain);
}
```

Here is what fiddler is giving me:

**Browser request 1 - response is 401**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Something HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

**Browser request 2 - response is 401**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Something HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB7IIogIAAgA0AAAADAAMACgAAAAGA9ckAAAAD0RFTEwyMDEzMDYwMUwy
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost
```

**Browser request 3 - response is 200 --> WORKED!**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Zusatz HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAAAAAAAFgAAAAAAAAAWAAAAAAAAABYAAAABcKIogYD1yQAAAAP9oJm9T9LmMQahBlQzRd2XA==
```

**Custom-application request 1 - response is 401**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Something HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Host: localhost
```

**Custom-application request 2 - response is 401**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Zusatz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGA9ckAAAADw==
Host: localhost
```

**Custom-application request 3 - response is 500 --> FAILED!**

```
GET http://localhost/WcfDataService.svc/Table/?$select=Zusatz HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Microsoft ADO.NET Data Services
MaxDataServiceVersion: 2.0;NetFx
Accept: application/atom+xml,application/xml
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
Authorization: NTLM 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
Host: localhost
```

In the response I get the following error-message:

```
Cannot open database "TEST" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

So I conclude that my request differs somehow from the browser-request which prevents the impersonation from working properly.

I´d really appreciate any hints on that.